# Ubuntu can't find or reogonize file

Tags: files, find

I've recently just installed Ubuntu, and it's been working fine, until now.
Ubuntu doesn't seem to regonize new files anymore. I just downloaded a file, put it in my desktop by GUI, and tried using the ls command in Desktop, but the file is not listed.

I tried on powershell, and there seems to be no problem there, only on ubuntu.

How do i fix this?

(Edit: Apparently if i use cd mnt/c/Users/(my user)/Desktop, i can find and list the file im looking for. But why can't i with just using cd Desktop? The difference (if i use pwd) is that the one which cant see my new file is located at "/home/(my user on ubuntu)/Desktop" while the one which CAN, was the first i mentioned (mnt/c/Users/(my user)/Desktop)
It regonizes my older files, but not my newer..

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Did you look in your Downloads directory too?  Latest Firefox puts everthing there, regardless of what you enter as download location.

Comment: I did indeed, and it is not there. But since i moved it from the downloads folder to just thr desktop, i didnt expect it to be there anyways.

Comment: Does the filename start with a dot? Those might show in a gui, but the default output of ls is to hide them.  Use ls -A ~/Desktop to show any hidden files.

Comment: It sounds like you are using WSL / WSLg and are confusing your native Windows "Desktop" with the Ubuntu ~/Desktop directory